# how does "case when index" statement compare to "case index" statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, case, teradata

I tried to research about this command, but I can't seem to find a concrete explanation to it.

What is "case when index"? what does it do? how is it differ from case when?
When is it used? 
Is this available to other RDMS or is it Teradata specific?
I would really it if you could provide some examples also.

Thank you so much.

```
sel
CASE    WHEN .00 = 0 THEN 0||'.' 
ELSE    .00 
END
,CASE   WHEN INDEX (.00,'.') = 0 THEN 0||'.' 
ELSE    .00 
END
```

Result:

```
  0.     .00
```

Comment: May be PATINDEX function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index() is a Teradata function.  You can read about it [here](http://www.sqlines.com/teradata/functions/index).  You can do the same sort of thing with other database engines, but not with that syntax.

Answer (score 1):

`CASE` is supported by both Oracle and SQL Server. The functions to find string position are different.

- In Oracle, use `INSTR` and put the string to search for second:

  ```
  INSTR('abcd', 'b')
  ```
- In SQL Server, use `CHARINDEX` and put the string to search for first:

  ```
  CHARINDEX('b', 'abcd')
  ```

The return value for each of the above will be `2`. In default installations, the Oracle function will be case sensitive and the SQL Server search won't, but it's best not to assume for either.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT -- Performs logical test of two numeric values (.00 = 0)
       CASE WHEN .00 = 0 
            THEN 0||'.' 
            ELSE .00 
       END
       -- Checks for the location of the of '.' in the string '.00'.
       -- In this test it returns 1. 1 <> 0.         
     , CASE WHEN INDEX (.00,'.') = 0  
            THEN 0||'.' 
            ELSE .00 
       END
```

`INDEX()` is a Teradata extension to the ANSI SQL:2008 standard. `POSITION()` is the ANSI SQL:2008 compliant equivalent. `POSITION('.' IN '.00)`